# Implementing IVsHierarchy

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

I would like to get started with implementing a new IVsHierarchy, however, i am not sure as to how this can be done, to be rephrasing i am not sure as to how the IVsHierarchy can be used.
Can someone share some example or shed some light on it ??

Comment: Was your question answered?  If not, is there something else you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the MPF for Projects. It contains implementation of IVsHierarchy. You can use it as base of your Project System.

http://mpfproj.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend reading [DiveDeeper's blog](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/) on VSX.

He has a number of posts on implementing IVsHierarchy:

- [Working with Hierarchies, Part 1](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/10/07/LearnVSXNowPart34.aspx)
- [Working with Hierarchies, Part 2](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/10/09/LearnVSXNowPart35.aspx)
- [Working with Hierarchies, Part 3](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/10/16/LearnVSXNowPart36.aspx)
- [Working with Hierarchies, Part 4](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/12/03/LearnVSXNowPart39.aspx)
- [Working with Hierarchies, Part 5](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/12/05/LearnVSXNowPart40.aspx)

He also has an [open source library called VSXtra](http://vsxtra.codeplex.com/) which provides lots of handy support code for writing VS Packages.  You may find it useful to use as a reference.

Comment: Links are dead.